# Stop functions executing at runtime/handle routing

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

Using F# template for ASP.NET MVC. Have routes defined a la

```
 app.UseRouting()
           .UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
                endpoints.MapGet("/", fun context ->
                    context.Response.WriteAsync(PageController.loadHomePage())) |> ignore

                endpoints.MapGet("/contact", fun context ->
                    context.Response.WriteAsync(PageController.loadContactPage())) |> ignore

                endpoints.MapGet("/about", fun context ->
                    context.Response.WriteAsync(PageController.loadAboutPage())) |> ignore
```

And then controller functions which all load the same page and simply sub in a title variable. The addVariable function simple replaces all instances of "[title]" with the string provided when loadTemplate is called.

```
module PageController

let loadHomePage() =
     Theme.addVariable "title" "Home Page"
     Theme.loadTemplate "index"


let loadContactPage() =
    Theme.loadTemplate "index"

let loadAboutPage() =
    Theme.addVariable "title" "About Us"
    Theme.loadTemplate "index"
```

However when I navigate to `/contact`, which does not a have a title variable defined, it has a title of "Home Page" which means `loadHomePage()` is being run and setting the title variable.

Am new to ASP.NET and F# so assuming it's super simple.

Edit:

```
(* Add variable function adds a value to a  dictionary *)
let mutable themeVars = new Dictionary<string, string>()

let addVariable name value =
        themeVars.[name] <- value

(* Load template, opens a file and runs "parseVariables" on the content *)

let ParseVariables (string:string) =
    Regex.Replace(string, "\[(.*?)\]",
        new MatchEvaluator(
            fun matchedVar ->
                let varName = matchedVar.Groups.[1].ToString()
                              |> StringTrim

                if themeVars.ContainsKey varName then
                    themeVars.[varName]
                else
                    "[Undefined Variable: " + varName + "]"
    ))

let loadTemplate templateName =
    if templateExists templateName then
        templateName
        |> getTemplateFilePath
        |> File.ReadAllText
        |> ParseVariables
    else
        "Missing Template: " + templateName + ""
```

Comment: Can you share the implementations of `addVariable` and `loadTemplate` so we can compile your code?

Comment: Thrown them in question. Addvariables sets a key in an empty dictionary. So what I want: when I visit `/contact`, I should get ` [Undefined Variable: title]`

Instead I'm getting `Home Page` which means the loadHomePage() is being run at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have a single mutable `themeVars` dictionary that is shared by all three pages. When your app starts, the home page is loaded, which adds a variable named `"Title"` to the dictionary. Then, when you visit the Contact page, that variable is still present in the dictionary, with whatever value it had last. (Could be either `"Home Page"` or `"About Us"`.)

To avoid this, create a separate immutable variable lookup for each page instead. Something like this:

```
let loadHomePage() =
    let themeVars = Map [ "Title", "Home Page" ]
    Theme.loadTemplate themeVars "index"

let loadContactPage() =
    let themeVars = Map.empty
    Theme.loadTemplate themeVars "index"

let loadAboutPage() =
    let themeVars = Map [ "Title", "About Us" ]
    Theme.loadTemplate themeVars "index"
```

Note that I've used a `Map` here instead of a `Dictionary`, since they're easier to deal with in F#, but the idea is the same either way.

Comment: It confuses me somewhat moving from interpreted to compiled language, so might be a more fundamental concept.

Comment: I'm a wary about values leaking from page to another or even across users. Does ASP track a session and use the same instance for a user? What if the same user opens the same page in different tabs, navigates to another page on one tab then refreshes the page in another? (testing this on local it seems if I open the app in Firefox and Opera, navigate to contact in both, then navigate to About in Firefox and refresh the instance in Opera, it also gets the "About" set as title. So they're using the exact same instance/session? Is there more reading I can do on how to approach?

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to avoid [shared mutable state](https://mb21.github.io/blog/2021/01/23/pure-functional-programming-and-shared-mutable-state.html) (such as your `themeVars` dictionary), which causes the problems you mentioned. In functional programming, we do this by writing "pure" functions that have no side-effects. That way, you can be certain that loading page X will have no unwanted effect on the behavior of page Y.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I get that and appreciate the code solution. I think the “problem” for me now is bigger picture and properly understanding how a compiled web application works. It just seems odd to me that a change to a variable would be allowed to persist across browsers.

Comment: The problem is more that changes to a variable are persisting in memory on the **server**. The page sent to a browser is just a view of the server's data at the time the page is generated. If you can avoid shared mutable data on the server (often called a "stateless" architecture), you don't have to worry much about complicated issues like instances, sessions, multiple tabs, multiple browsers, etc.